# thingsboard mqtt scripts use din dashboard videos published

Tags: thingsboard

I saw TB videos published few days ago on maps and visualization. Impressive.

There were some scripts used to publish , subscribe request data for devices.

Can you share the objective and tasks performed by the scripts used for thermostat, energy and water-meters devices?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts are self explanatory javascript applications based on mqtt-js. You can find links to the scripts in the video description.

Comment: Yes, the description was hidden in the youtube page, my bad. Very helpful, Thingsboard team and Andrew!

Comment: Hi, How to redirect to custome login page to thingsboard.io/home using auth/login API, Please if you have knowledge can you share with us.